# Is there a way to reduce tile processing from Openlayers 3 when user pan & zoom a lot?

Tags: geojson, openlayers, tiles, performance

I have 2 overlays with local tiles (xyz) on my map.
When the user zoom in / out and pan the map intentionally a lot, the app becomes very slow because OL tries to render all the tiles it was requested by the pan & zoom, but they are no longer needed on the view because the user zoomed out from there.

Is there a way to reduce this load? Will it be faster if instead of xyz layer I'll use geojson layer with styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to be a on a fairly low-tech machine, or be zooming/panning via automation in order to have issues rendering only two XYZ layers.  I suspect your issue is related to something else.  If it was an actual issue, you could employ a bounds/extent trigger to stop rendering and halt network traffic for tiles that are out of view.  That being said, OpenLayers does do this in the background for you.

Try creating a new OL3 map with *just* your two XYZ layers and see if you have the same issue.  You can then use a browser profiler or network proxy (like Fiddler) to see where the performance issue might be.

Further to your question on GeoJSON v XYZ, if you decided to render GeoJSON, you're asking the browser engine to do a whole lot more than simply display an XYZ tile.  Unless your data is *very* simple, then you're not going to get a performance boost from rendering the data yourself.

Comment: This answer doesnt hold true at this date, OpenLayers sends a lot of requests even while zooming and panning , such a mature library but still this functionality is so hard to hit.